# powering 2 DC motors

Tags: motor, dc, interference

I have two 2.5A 12V DC motors running fans at high rpms. When I hook up one to my 10A 12V DC power supply it works great. When I hook both up the motors just pulse, turning a revolution or two every second or so. I would love to know what I am missing.

Comment: can you put a schematic of how youve wired them up

Answer (score 6):

Motors require several times rated current when they start. Both motors starting simultaneously probably draw enough current to make the power supply shut down to protect itself. After a second or two, the power supply resets itself and the same thing happens again. Try switching the motors on one at a time.

Comment: Thanks!, That makes sense. I did not know the spike was that much. will try that and see if that is the cause. A capacitor would fix that?

Comment: A capacitor might help, but it may be difficult for the power supply to charge a large enough capacitor. You can add a resistor to limit the charging current, but it would be better not to have the resistor in the circuit when the motors are running.

Comment: Definitely make sure the power supply can start the second motor with the first one running.